# Does django already come with a wsgi application file, or do I need to create one? How to setup apache and mod_wsgi with django?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a web app with django, however I am having trouble with Apache and mod_wsgi. I have scoured the tutorials online, and none of them have provided me with accurate/sufficient information on how to set this up. I understand that I need an application.wsgi file/ a wsgi application file, however I am not sure as to whether I have to create on, or if django is pre-built with one. If django does come with one, how do I tell apache to display my django app?

I am currently using Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I can do a `runserver` and see the application from localhost, however I want to fully deploy the website. In other words, when I type in the IP of the server I want to see the home page that I made with django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django documentation has a guide that explains this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I tried looking at that, but when I get to the mod_wsgi tutorial which is linked on the django doc that you pointed me to, I get to the part where I have to run the command 'make' and I get an error 'fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory'....

Comment: Please try this: `$ sudo apt-get install python-dev` and then try running make again.

Comment: great that works! but I still have an issue as for I cannot find the httpd.conf in my files, so I cannot Load the mod_wsgi module

Comment: Yeah I read that post however, I am getting mixed up because in the mod_wsgi tutorial it says "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so", however, if it is true that Ubuntu doesn't have an httpd.conf in the local user apache directory, then why does the 'make install' command install the modules in 'usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so', if apache2.conf is in 'etc/apache2/', when I load the module should I just specify the local user path?

Comment: Additionally, the wsgi.py file, which is what I was originally struggling with....where is that? do I have to make that in the root directory?

Comment: wsgi.py should be in your project folder next to your settings.py (i.e. myproject/myproject/wsgi.py)

Comment: Okay so all that is done then, but then how does it server the files to display what I want ? Because I have a static folder, but I also have a templates folder, and I am issuing a collectstatic command but the files do not transfer to the static foldr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112210/discussion-between-m-barbieri-and-grez).